# When does reward occur? When dopamine is released or when it is binded?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

I know this is a silly question, but I'm curious as to what is the exact phase when we experience of the thrill of doing an exciting activity.

I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_transporter) briefly describes the whole process. So, what is the exact point where we feel like "rewarded", when dopamine is released or when it is binded to one of its intended [receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_receptor#Dopamine_receptor_subtypes)?

Comment: Dopamine isn't responsible for the experience of reward.  The more likely candidates are endogenous opioid and cannabinoid signals.

Comment: We would love to see that as an answer(with refs.) @mrt

Comment: I'm not sure I have an answer to your exact question, but if you're interested in contemporary theory about reward and dopamine's role in the brain, see [Berridge & Kringelbach, 2015](http://www.kringelbach.org/papers/Neuron_BerridgeKringelbach2015.pdf) and [Friston et al., 2012](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002327).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of feed forward systems is that the uptake of transmitter would induce the effect. Though, the simultaneous release of more dopamine is part of its effect. The synaptic gap has no mechanism of inducing a response to a transmitter besides the reuptake on the other side. I am no sort of professional so take what I say with a grain.